# Javascript saving mode in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, memory-consumption

I made a little code  in JavaScript which play music on a streaming music website ( tidal, spotify napster etc... ) and change every x seconds. When the last song is listening it loops and plays the first song of the playlist. ( I made this because on tidal.com webmaster didn't implement the functionality to loop the entire playlist ).

I injected my javascript using Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey on firefox and chrome and i got problems when i have 10 tabs opened ( so 10 javascript loop working together ). I'm a beginner so maybe my code is really bad, just tell me.

So the code isn't complicated, i get the DOM element which will allow me to controls songs ( next / pause / first song ), and i .click() on those buttons when my conditions are true. It works when i have ONE tab opened, i can see it is doing its purpose.

But the problem is, when i run it with like 10 or 15 tabs opened, my browser seems to stop my javascript because i'm not on the page. I can see that as soon as i come back on the page the script wake up and works. ( For example sometimes i come back on a page and i can see a song which is at 2:00 while i set in my code to go next when time is 35s.. )

So : Is my code completely buggy or is it the browser ? Chrome/Firefox do the same. And BTW, i tested by injecting directly with the console ( F12 ) and it's the same.

```js
//First track of the playlist
var firstTrack;

//Next button
var next;
//current time
var time; 
var lastTrackPlaying; //null if we are not on the last track

var paused; //null if we are playing


function initVar() {

 firstTrack = document.querySelector("button[title='Lire']");
 next = document.getElementsByClassName("play-controls__next js-next")[0];
  
  setInterval(checkTime,5000); //every 5sec, call checkTime
  
}
 

function checkTime() {
 time = document.getElementsByClassName("js-progress")[0].innerHTML; 
 time = 60*Number(time[0]) + Number( time[2] + time[3]); //convert the time to int format
 lastTrackPlaying = document.querySelector("tr[class='js-tracklist__row ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle is-active is-playing'][data-track-id='86656183']");
 paused = document.getElementsByClassName("play-controls__main-button js-main-button play-controls__main-button--paused")[0];

 if( (lastTrackPlaying != null) && ( time >= 35  ) ) firstTrack.click(); //we are on last song, play first

 else if (  time >= 35 ) next.click(); //next song if 35 sec spent

 else if ( paused != null) firstTrack.click(); //if the playlist is paused, play the first song

}



setTimeout(initVar, 5000); //start the code with 5sec delay ( the website load )
```

Answer (score 0):

This occures because browsers tend to slow down intervals in inactive tabs to optimize the performance.

Check out the [MDN for setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval):

> Inactive tabs Requires Gecko 5.0(Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 /
>   SeaMonkey 2.2)
>
> Starting in Gecko 5.0 (Firefox 5.0 / Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2),
>   intervals are clamped to fire no more often than once per second in
>   inactive tabs.

Comment: But, in fact if you check my code you will seevsetInterval(checkTime,5000);

So, i call it every 5 seconds, so normally it is okay, the limitation is about every function called less than 1/sec...

Comment: Yes you are right! :D I also noticed that. Does your problem already happen when you have two tabs open? Because maybe the browsers make it even slower when you have 10 or more tabs open like you wrote in your question.

Comment: Yeap i checked. As soon at the tab is unfocused, the code doens't work in background...
Maybe it seems that i have to use a unoptimised browser.. ( maybe internet explorer 2 o 3 will do the trick )